# I need help on figuring out how to get the isset() function to work

Tags: php, html

Create a new PHP file called lab2.php.
Inside, add the HTML skeleton code and give its title “Lab Week 2”.
Create a form asking for the person’s name and favourite ice cream flavour.
Store the data using variables.
Use the isset function to check.
Print the results.

[PHP CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeFUJ.png)
[HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF0fs.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should use POST request for sending data from user(.html file) to server(.php file).

In your HTML file, comment this

```
//<form action="lab2.php" method="get">
```

and use this

```
<form action="lab2.php" method="post">
```

In yout PHP file, you can get data using

```
if(isset($_POST['icecream'])) {
  echo $_POST['icecream']
}
```

Comment: Is there any way I could use $_GET because that's what I have to use